# Gravity forms conditions

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm working on a form with specific values for one field, we are making a campaign with 20,000 codes and the user must enter the code he gets in a field in gravity form, so this field will have 20,000 values and restricted with these codes, so when the users enter any value they will get a message that this value is wrong and enter the right value, i need to add if statement for these 20,000 values to restrict the field with it using one statement not like the confirmation message in the plugin i have to add the value one by one. please help me with it.

please help me.

Comment: You need to show some code in your question, indicating what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are a non-coder but let me know if that is a bad assumption. Here's a customization-free technique for achieving this. We have a snippet that will allow you to required a reference number (or code) in order to submit a Gravity Form.

https://gravitywiz.com/require-existing-value-submission-gravity-forms/

The only problem for you is that it can only look for reference numbers in existing Gravity Forms entries. To get your codes converted to entries we can import them use [GravityView Import Entries](https://gravityview.co/extensions/gravity-forms-entry-importer/?ref=129).

Once the codes are imported as entries, just configure the snippet to check for those codes in the newly imported form/entries. The user will not be able to submit the form unless they enter a valid code.